# Rails 4 - concerns for generic validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activesupport-concern

I just ran across Rails concerns and I want to use them for the validations of my models. But I want the validations to be generic, so that the validation is used only if the Class in which I include my concern has the attribute. I thought it would be easy, but I have tried many ways like using column_names, constantize, send and many other but nothing works. What is the right way to do it? The code:

```
module CommonValidator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :email, presence: { message: I18n.t(:"validations.commons.email_missing") }, 
                      format: { with: /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i, 
                      message: I18n.t(:"validations.commons.email_wrong_format"), 
                            allow_blank: true } if self.column_names.include? :email
  end
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CommonValidator
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Restaurant of course has an email attribute. Is it possible to check the existence of an attribute in the class in which in include my concern? I want include my CommonValidations into many models which will not have email attribute. I'm using rails 4.

Comment: This is a very lazy and brittle pattern/technique. You're better off creating an `EachValidator` and using it per column a la `validates :email, email_address: true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`respond_to?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) on the current instance as follows:

```
validates :email, presence: { message: I18n.t(:"validations.commons.email_missing") }, 
                  format: { with: /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i, 
                  message: I18n.t(:"validations.commons.email_wrong_format"), 
                  allow_blank: true }, 
                  if: lambda { |o| o.respond_to?(:email) }
```

Another option as suggested by @coreyward is to define a class extending `EachValidator`. For example, for email validation:

```
# app/validators/email_validator.rb
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || I18n.t(:"validations.commons.email_wrong_format"))
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could update the validation call as:

```
validates :email, 
          presence: { message: I18n.t(:"validations.commons.email_missing") },
          email: true, 
          allow_blank: true
```

Comment: EachValidator is a possibility and I will reconsider it's usage, but the usage of respond_to? is not working. My goal was to have for example "validates :aaa ...." where :aaa is a random string which the model Restaurant does NOT have. Now it just raise NoMethodError. In short, I want to be able to include validation on non-existent attribute, so i can easily include CommonValidations in many models which doesn't have to have all the attributes.

Comment: @Giron, It's working for me with the following: `validates :email, presence: true, if: lambda { |o| o.respond_to?(:email) }`, can you update your question to include the error you're getting?

Comment: I'll update it as soon as I get home in about 10 hours.

Comment: The solution is right, I had a silly typo in my code. Thank you for your time, I can imagine scenarios when I would use both of the methods, but I agree with coreyward, that the usage for such a "smart" validations can be really brittle.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar, but with custom validations.
I ended up with something that I think could be shared, including generic tests.

First, set up the concern `app/models/concern/my_concern.rb`.

Please note that we don't define the `validate_my_field` into a `ClassMethods` module.

```
module MyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validate :my_field, :validate_my_field
  end

private

  def validate_my_field
    ...
  end

end
```

Include concern into your model `app/models/my_model.rb`

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyConcern
end
```

Load concerns shared examples in `spec/support/rails_helper`:

```
…
  Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/concerns/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
…
```

Create concern shared examples `spec/concerns/models/my_field_concern_spec.rb`:

```
RSpec.shared_examples_for 'my_field_concern' do
  let(:model) { described_class } # the class that includes the concern

  it 'has a valid my_field' do
    instance = create(model.to_s.underscore.to_sym, my_field: …)
    expect(instance).not_to be_valid
    …
  end
end
```

Then finally call shared examples into your model spec `spec/models/my_model_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyModel do
  include_examples 'my_field_concern'

  it_behaves_like 'my_field_concern'
end
```

I hope this could help.